# Is there a way to deactivate lines of code in Visual studio without deleting them?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to deactivate several lines of code in visual studio?

I'm currently typing // in from of each line when I need to deactivate a segment of code (for debugging etc), but it gets tiresome.

Comment: Select your text; then `CTRL` + `SLASH` does the trick.

Comment: Also, please specify if its `Visual Studio`, or `Visual Studio Code`, they are two different things, and the tag makes it confusing. My solution works the same for both out of the box.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I swapped the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts
```

Search for `Toggle Line Comment` And edit the key combintion and choose whatever you want to perform that action

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, use `/*` and `*/` for multi-line comment - this will make the code not run. Example:

```
printf("This code will run\n");

/*
printf("This code will not run\n");
printf("nor will this\n");
*/
```

In Python you use `"""` for multi-line comments. Other languages might have different ones.